# Openlayers export to KML and keep my map styles

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml

I successfully write a KML from Openlayers, however no styles (colors, stroke, etc.) are present in the kml file.  Is it possible to generate the KML with the styles?

I found a similar question here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/openlayers-format-kml-write-style

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of yet the WRITE method does not make use of the `'extractStyles':true,` property as you can see [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Format/KML.js?rev=12434). Only the READ method does.

The only way I saw was simply to recreate them. In the example below, I've created the KML style I wanted and **Injected it** into openlayers created kml string.

```js
myorg.Util.GetKMLFromFeatures = function (features, strfolderName, strfolderDescription) {

    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'maxDepth': 10,
        'extractStyles': true,
        'internalProjection': myorg.UI.Map.getMap().baseLayer.projection,
        'externalProjection': myorg.UI.Map.Projections.Geographic
    });

    var kmlStyle = "<Style id='OutlineOnlyStyle'><PolyStyle><color>ff0000cc</color><fill>0</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style>";

    format.foldersName = strfolderName;
    format.foldersDesc = strfolderDescription;

    //add style description
    var kml = format.write(features).replace(/<Folder>/g, '<Folder>' + kmlStyle)
    .replace(/><name>/g, '><styleUrl>#OutlineOnlyStyle</styleUrl><name>');

    return kml;

};
```