# How to export the feature's properties as a KML file?

Tags: openlayers, kml

I can normally import a KML file and see the properties, as name and other custom ones. But when I export this same feature the file contains only the geometry. I'm using the `writeFeatures()` function and as far as I can see there is nothing mentioning about this in [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_KML-KML.html#writeFeatures). Is there a way to export with these properties?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11991387/7123439) that for styles these must be injected manually, perhaps is the same for the properties? However, I believe this approach will have a bit more work because it will be necessary to search for each placemark tag, navigate through them and then inject the properties. How is this done conventionally nowadays?

Comment: Which version are you using?  The answer you linked refers to OpenLayers 2.  The current version is a complete rewrite and will export both names and styles https://codesandbox.io/s/kml-z1tob

Comment: I'm using version 5.3.3, maybe this is the problem, but I don't know if I can update in this project without breaking something. I going to try it anyway.

Comment: When upgrading to version 6.3.1 some critical functions like pan and select features broke, these are the ones I have been able to notice so far. For now I think I will follow the idea of developing a manual function to export the properties. Thanks for your help nonetheless.